# Double click on Windows Service executable to configure

Tags: delphi, windows-services

I wrote a Delphi Win32 Windows Service application from Delphi IDE's template, and it works very well when installed and started from Services control panel.

Now I would like to write a configuration application for it and I thought that may be it could be a configurator for itself when just double clicking on its executable.

I think so because when double clicked, the service distinguishes somehow that it wasn't executed by Service Control Management system.

So here are my questions:

1. How does the Service app distinguishes a simple run and run as a service?
2. Could the simple run be used to take some actions other than a service mode? Will this disturb functioning in a service mode?

Comment: Surely it's so much simpler to write a separate program for this. Surely you don't want your service executable to be full of VCL GUI code. As a rule, take the path of least resistance. Adapt your program design to the underlying platform. Don't try to bend the platform to your imaginings because it's not flexible.

Comment: David,I do this all the time, what is the issue?

Comment: I also do this, when starting with a parameter it starts as an application in stead of a service. So I have the same question, what is the issue ?

Comment: Just seems wrong to bundle the VCL into a service executable. What you have is two programs, a service program and a GUI program. They are disjoint. Yes you can stuff them into the same executable and execute one path or other depending on command line, but what's the benefit? I'd keep them separate and isolated.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I get your point but for smaller projects this is much easier & I only have to maintain one executable without worrying that the config application may read/write incorrect information for my service application.

Comment: @whosrdaddy Well, fair enough, but GUI code in a service just makes me 

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Actually, services in Delphi are based on VCL, and already use numerous VCL units internally. Just recently I tried to create my own stripped version, but it highly relies on VCL, especially in `Vcl.Forms`.

Comment: @Jerry Whilst `Vcl.SvcManager` uses the `Vcl.Forms` unit, it doesn't actually call a whole lot there. Mostly relating to exception handling in `TApplication`. But you are right in that is feels galling for a service application to use VCL units at all. I think it should be quite easy to write a service without any reference to the VCL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

to answer your questions:

> How does the Service app distinguishes a simple run and run as a
>   service?

**look at the code behind `TServiceApplication.CreateForm` in unit `Vcl.SVcMgr`**

> Could the simple run be used to take some actions other than a service
>   mode?

**Yes, see below answer**

> Will this disturb functioning in a service mode?

**No**

All you need to do is change your Service source code (.dpr file) to something like this:

```
 begin
  if FindCmdLineSwitch('config', ['-', '/'], True) then
   TMyForm.Run
  else
   begin
    if not Application.DelayInitialize or Application.Installing then
     Application.Initialize;
    Application.CreateForm(TSvc_MyService, Svc_MyService);
    Application.Run;
   end;
end.
```

where TMyForm.Run is defined as a class procedure on my main GUI form:

```
class procedure TMyForm.Run;
begin
 TThread.NameThreadForDebugging('FormRunner');
 ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := DebugHook <> 0;
 Forms.Application.Initialize;
 Forms.Application.ShowMainForm := True;
 Forms.Application.MainFormOnTaskBar := True;
 Forms.Application.CreateForm(TMyForm, MyForm);
 Forms.Application.Run;
end;
```

So when you start the service executable with flag /config (or -config), it will start as a normal forms application.

**Update**

The distinction is more likely to be made here:

```
procedure TServiceStartThread.Execute;
begin
  if StartServiceCtrlDispatcher(FServiceStartTable[0]) then
    ReturnValue := 0
  else
    ReturnValue := GetLastError; //Code 1063 if started like an app
end;
```

This causes WM_QUIT message to be posted to message queue.

Following loop terminates when receives `WM_QUIT` message.

```
procedure TServiceApplication.Run;
.....
begin
  .....
  while not Vcl.Forms.Application.Terminated do
  try
    Vcl.Forms.Application.HandleMessage;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      DoHandleException(E);
  end;
  .....
end;
```

More information on the topic here:

- [Writing a Service Program's main Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/services/writing-a-service-program-s-main-function)
- [StartServiceCtrlDispatcherA function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-startservicectrldispatchera)

Comment: When you double click on an executable it doesn't pass `/config` on the command line

Comment: no correct, that's why my installer application creates a shortcut with the parameter passed to the command line

Comment: ..or you could turn the logic around and install the service to start with a parameter e.g. /service, and start as config UI with no parameters.

Comment: The user asked about double clicking the executable though

Comment: @whosrdaddy actually, you didn't. You answered how to run the configuration UI when a `config` command line is passed in to the EXE, which does not happen when the user just double clicks on the EXE. Your solution requires a separate shortcut. OndrejKelle's solution is the correct answer to what the OP asked for.